# How to use annotations with z3c.form's DictionaryField

Tags: plone, zope, z3c.form

There is [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/z3c.form/form.html?highlight=datamanager#creating-edit-forms-for-dictionaries) on using Python `dict` `with z3c.form` (loading & storing form data).

However, the `z3c.form` `datamanager` used for dicts is not registered for other types or interfaces (see [reference](https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.form/blob/3.2.7/src/z3c/form/datamanager.py#L110-L114)), whereas annotations typically use something like `PersistentDict`.

How can I use the `DictionaryField` `datamanager` in this scenario? Ie. so that in my form's `getContent` method I merely return the `PersistentDict`annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, unfortunately there seems no simple solution for this requirement. 
I once faced the same problem using the datagrid field in a z3c form.

The following instruction solves the problem for the datagrid field, which is a `list` (PersistentList of `dicts` (PersistentMappings).

I guess you may adapt this solution for your case.

First  you need to add the following code to the `getContent` method:

```
from plone.directives import form

class MyForm(form.SchemaEditForm):

    schema = IMyFormSchema
    ignoreContext = False

    def getContent(self):
        annotations = IAnnotations(self.context)
        if ANNOTATION_KEY not in annotations:
            annotations[ANNOTATION_KEY] = PersistentMapping()
        return YourStorageConfig(annotations[ANNOTATION_KEY])
```

**Important note:** I wrap the annotation storage to satisfy the get/set behavior of the z3c form. Check the following `YourStorageConfig` implementation and you will see why :-).

```
class YourStorageConfig(object):
    implements(IMyFormSchema)

    def __init__(self, storage):
        self.storage = storage

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'storage':
            return object.__getattr__(self, name)
        value = self.storage.get(name)
        return value

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'storage':
            return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        if name == 'yourfieldname':
            self.storage[name] = PersistentList(map(PersistentMapping, value))
            return

        raise AttributeError(name)
```

`yourfieldname` should be the field name you are using in the form schema.

To implement the a datagrid field, there is some more work to do, but this may be enough for your case.

Please post comments, or tracebacks, so I can provide further help. I'll gonna add more details/explanation if necessary ;-)

Comment: I see... I am thinking the above wrapper, turned into an adapter that multiadapts (PersistentList & zope.schema IField) to IDataManager would be similar to what I am looking for... However in my case the adapter  already exists (z3c.form DictionaryField), I think just need to find a way to register/enable it for PersistentDict.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the answer is as easy as the following ZCML adapter registration:

```
<adapter
  for="persistent.dict.PersistentDict zope.schema.interfaces.IField"
  provides="z3c.form.interfaces.IDataManager"
  factory="z3c.form.datamanager.DictionaryField"
 />
```

With that, the following customization of a form is sufficient to use (`PersistentDict`) annotations for loading & storing form data:

```
def getContent(self):
   "return the object the form will manipulate (load from & store to)"
   annotations =  IAnnotations(self.context)
   return annotations[SOME_ANNOTATIONS_KEY_HERE]
```

This is assuming that a `PersistentDict` has been previously stored at `annotations[SOME_ANNOTATIONS_KEY_HERE]` - otherwise the above code will result in `KeyError`. It would probably be a good idea to change above `getContent` so that if the annotation does not yet exist, it is created and initialized with some default values.

Finally, note that for some reason, `z3c.form` [warns](https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.form/blob/3.2.7/src/z3c/form/datamanager.py#L110-L114) against enabling `DictionaryField` for every mapping type, so it may be prudent to for example subclass `PersistentDict` for form storage, rather than use it directly. I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.form/issues/33) to z3c.form asking for clarification of that warning.